# jQuery on each click of parent change child only

Tags: jquery, each

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0b4etshr/1/

How can I make the text of on each `item_ k` change color ( toggleClass() ) when the input is checked?

```
$('item_').each(function(){
  $(".iOScb").click(function(){             
    $('item_ k').toggleClass("active");

            });
        });
```

Do not work.

Comment: Please the post the HTML from your linked Fiddle into the question (use the [edit] link below the question to do so); also, while you can create custom elements it's better not to, in the event that - as unlikely as it may seem - that those elements are used for a specific purpose in the future. Also, it's invalid HTML which tends to upset JavaScript and makes it, and the DOM, behave erratically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("item_ [type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  $("k", $(this).parents("item_")).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Basically, any time a checkbox contained in the `<item_>` tag changes its state, the `k` tag contained in `<item_>` but in an level upper than the checkbox toggles the `active` class.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ... and how can I "disable" them all  with onclick function? (revert them to default state)

Comment: If by "them" you mean the `k` nodes, you should be able to do `$('item_ k').removeClass('active')`.

Comment: No these, I mean to "de-check" everything (disable :checked).

Comment: Ah, in that case: `$('item_ [type="checkbox"]).prop('checked', false)`.

Comment: This probably fits better in a separate question.